# Modifying Google OAuth2 login page

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to modify or show a more iOS friendly login page from googles oauth2 services? I'm not sure if I have seen a modified on before but i can't find any information on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only change you can do is to provide your own logo as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Register

To make the login process more like a part of your application it is possible to open the login page in an embedded browser instead of open it in Safari, but you will not be able to change how it looks.